# Battery problems with Ubuntu Touch

Tags: 14.04

So I installed Ubuntu Touch 14.04 on my Nexus 7 2013 and it will only charge when turned off and it takes forever to charge, like after four hours I am only at 40% or that is what the battery icon says. Do you think the icon is not reading correctly or do you think there is something wrong and it is not charging correctly?